# How to defer expanding a parameter pack?

Tags: c++17, variadic-templates, stdtuple, parameter-pack, fold-expression

I was toying around with tuples. I wanted to zip an arbitrary number of tuples. There is probably a better way to do that than what I came up with, but my solution led me to a problem that is interesting in itself.

Sometimes, you want to expand one parameter pack at a time, and those parameter packs can be template arguments and function arguments in the same call. I could not find an obvious way to expand `Is` without expanding `ts`, besides stuffing `ts` into a `std::tuple` and unpacking it again using `std::get<I>`.

Obviously, it's preferable not to split one function into five functions. I know I could use lambdas, but I'm not sure that would be any cleaner.

Is there a nice way to defer expanding `ts`?

https://godbolt.org/z/sY5xMTa7P

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <string_view>

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
auto get_first(T t, Ts...) {
    return t;
}

template <size_t I, typename... Ts>
auto zip2_impl4(Ts... ts) {
    return std::make_tuple(std::get<I>(ts)...);
}

template <size_t I, typename T, size_t... Is>
auto zip2_impl3(T t, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return zip2_impl4<I>(std::get<Is>(t)...);
}

template <size_t I, typename T>
auto zip2_impl2(T t) {
    using size = std::tuple_size<T>;
    using seq = std::make_index_sequence<size::value>;
    return zip2_impl3<I>(t, seq{});
}

template <size_t... Is, typename... Ts>
auto zip2_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...> seq, Ts... ts) {
    // need to defer expanding the pack ts,
    // because the packs Is and ts need to expand separately
    auto t = std::make_tuple(ts...);
    return std::make_tuple(zip2_impl2<Is>(t)...);
}

template <typename... Ts>
auto zip2(Ts... ts) {
    using size = std::tuple_size<decltype(get_first(ts...))>;
    using seq = std::make_index_sequence<size::value>;
    return zip2_impl(seq{}, ts...);
}

int main() {
    using namespace std::literals;
    auto ints = std::make_tuple(1,2,3);
    auto svs1 = std::make_tuple("a"sv, "b"sv, "c"sv);
    auto svs2 = std::make_tuple("d"sv, "e"sv, "f"sv);
    auto zipped = zip2(ints, svs1, svs2);

    std::apply([](auto... args) {
        (std::apply([](auto... args) {
            ((std::cout << args), ...);
        }, args), ...);
    }, zipped);

    return 0;
}
```

```
output: 1ad2be3cf
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47210956/c17-multiple-parameter-pack-expansion?rq=1

That Q/A unfortunately doesn't have a title that lends itself to good discoverability (I didn't find it when I searched SO).

Comment: Relevant: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200529-00/?p=103810

Comment: If the edit doesn't go through, for future viewers, just change `std::tuple_cat` to `std::make_tuple` to get the format `std::tuple<std::tuple<>, ...>` a tuple of tuples, where each inner tuple corresponds to an index of the tuples given to `zip`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly:
https://godbolt.org/z/e4fvr45rz

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
#include <cstddef>

template <size_t Indx,typename ... Tuples>
constexpr auto zip(Tuples ... tuples)
{
    return std::make_tuple(std::get<Indx>(tuples)...);
}

template <typename ... Tuples, size_t ... Indx>
constexpr auto zip(std::index_sequence<Indx...>, Tuples... tuples)
{
    // will expand simultaneously, not what you want...
    // return std::make_tuple(std::make_tuple(std::get<Indx>(tuples)...));
    return std::make_tuple(zip<Indx>(tuples...)...);
}

template <typename ... Tuples>
constexpr auto zip(Tuples ... tuples)
{
    return zip(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Tuples)>(), tuples...);
}

#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::literals;
    auto ints = std::make_tuple(1,2,3);
    auto svs1 = std::make_tuple("a"sv, "b"sv, "c"sv);
    auto svs2 = std::make_tuple("d"sv, "e"sv, "f"sv);
    auto zipped = zip(ints, svs1, svs2);

    std::apply([](auto... args) {
        (std::apply([](auto... args) {
            ((std::cout << args), ...);
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }, args), ...);
    }, zipped);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Program returned: 0
1ad
2be
3cf
```

So there is a way, I guess. You have to have your parameter packs in  different contexts: one in the function arguments, another in the template argumetns. If you try to expand both packs in one "context" you will get a compile-time error:

```
// this will not compile
// return std::make_tuple(std::make_tuple(std::get<Indx>(tuples)...)...);

// and this will expand them simultaneously, giving you "1bf" as a result
return std::make_tuple(std::make_tuple(std::get<Indx>(tuples)...));
```

---

UPDATE:
https://godbolt.org/z/9E1zj5q4G - more generic solution:

```
template <typename FirstTuple, typename ... Tuples>
constexpr auto zip(FirstTuple firstTuple, Tuples ... tuples)
{
    return zip(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<FirstTuple>>(), firstTuple, tuples...);
}
```

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std::literals;
    auto ints = std::make_tuple(1,2,3);
    auto svs1 = std::make_tuple("a"sv, "b"sv, "c"sv);
    auto svs2 = std::make_tuple("d"sv, "e"sv, "f"sv);    
    auto svs3 = std::make_tuple("g"sv, "h"sv, "i"sv);

    auto zipped = zip(ints, svs1, svs2, svs3);

    std::apply([](auto... args) {
        (std::apply([](auto... args) {
            ((std::cout << args), ...);
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }, args), ...);
    }, zipped);

    return 0;
}
```

```
Output:
1adg
2beh
3cfi
```

Instead of number of tuples you pass a number of elements. You have to be sure that each tuple has at least as many elements as the first one. Extra elements will be truncated. If there are too few elements, there will be a compilation error from `std::get<>`.

Comment: That's great! I tried something like this, and I kept getting an error saying there was no pack to expand for the second ellipse. I can change my solution to be like yours and figure out what the problem was. This is exactly what I hoped for :)

Comment: @okovko also take notice, that functions can also be overloaded by a different template signature unlike class templates)